# Merging 2 folders in java keeping the common files by changing its name

Tags: java, file, file-io, io, merge

There are about 15 folders that I have. Every folder has a similar sub-structure. I was to merge the contents of the folders:
 1. taking 2 folders at a time
 2. taking 3 folders at a time Such that both files with same name are saved.

Example:

```
folder 1 
---pqr
------abc.txt
------xyz.txt

folder 2
---pqr
------abc.txt
```

after merging:

```
folder 3
---pqr
-------abc.txt
-------abc.txt(2)
-------xyz.txt
```

Please help me with a java code.  Thanks in advance.

This is what I have done so far in netbeans.

```
package merger;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Merger {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }

    public void copyDifferentFolderFilesIntoOne(String mergedFolderStr,
            String... foldersStr) throws IOException
    {

        final File mergedFolder = new File(mergedFolderStr);
        final Map<String, File> filesMap = new HashMap<> ();
        for (String folder : foldersStr) {
            updateFilesMap(new File (folder), filesMap, null);
        }

        for (final Map.Entry<String, File> fileEntry : filesMap.entrySet()) {
            final String relativeName = fileEntry.getKey();
            final File srcFile = fileEntry.getValue();
            FileUtils.copyFile (srcFile, new File (mergedFolder, relativeName));
        }
    }

    private void updateFilesMap(final File baseFolder, final Map<String, File> filesMap,
            final String relativeName)
    {
        for (final File file : baseFolder.listFiles()) {
            final String fileRelativeName = getFileRelativeName (relativeName, file.getName());

            if (file.isDirectory())
            {           
                updateFilesMap(file, filesMap, fileRelativeName);
            }
            else {
                final File existingFile = filesMap.get (fileRelativeName);
                if (existingFile == null || file.lastModified() > existingFile.lastModified() ) {
                    filesMap.put (fileRelativeName, file);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String getFileRelativeName(final String baseName, final String fileName)
    {
        return baseName == null ? fileName : baseName + "/" + fileName;
    }    
}
```